# How to add wiki pages to web-part page?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part-page, wiki-pages

Salve!

EasyTabs works on a web-part page.
I want users to be able to create wizzywig pages with, say, the "create page" which creates a blank wiki page.

Then I want to use the web-part page that has EasyTabs on it to show those wiki pages in the web-parts there.

Problem is, that the only way to get the wiki pages into the web-parts is through a web-part viewer, and when you do that, it displays all the site's title, ribbon and navigation inside the web-part.

I tried a content-editor and linked to the page, but it displays the source instead of the page!

What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a "Wiki Library" that houses wiki pages - in this library's settings, there is a field called "wiki content" by which you can display the content without all the surrounding navigation.

Try the following:
Add the Wiki Web Part associated with your Wiki library, then Configure it to only display "Wiki content" and filtered for the name of the page you wanted to display.  If you don't filter by the page name, every wiki page in that library will be displayed.  And if you don't check the box for "wiki content" in the list settings, then you will get columns for "created by", "title", etc. like you would with a regular list.

[This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/sharepoint2010general/thread/497ba316-650a-45cb-8e17-4dc7abe88ca4) link is helpful.

Comment: I'm sorry, there isn't any "wiki web part", and I don't have any "wiki library".  I am not using a "wiki site", you see.  I have a publishing site where I create a new page where you can edit the page right there in the browser (it is called "wiki").

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean.  I didn't really want to use a wiki library; I wanted to create the new wiki page in my SitePages library.  But, what you have suggested will certainly work.  I edited your answer to add a helpful link.

Answer (score 0):

As far as easytabs goes, if you don't want to use a wiki library, you can, instead, do a couple other things:

- write out some simple html in a text editor, save the file as an html file, and upload it to your document library.  Now you can reference the file with file-link via a content editor webpart.  This will avoid any scrollbars which you would get with a web-page-viewer.  You can keep and edit the original copies of these html files (complete with javascript and css in-page) on your local disk, and upload them programmatically using [davcopy](http://www.bluedoglimited.com/Downloads/pages/DavCopy.aspx).  The value to this method is that you can easily deal with your own css styles.  If you are using a custom css file in your master page, then you can reuse the same styles throughout all of your site, and even in these html inserts.  It isn't so easy to use css styles (although you definitely can do it) in the wizzywig wiki pages because Sharepoint wants to style things it's own way.  But this method allows you to *reuse* your html inserts in other places.
- Or, you can write your html directly into the content-editor webpart.  Again, you can use styles and script there.  This is fine as long as you don't need to re-use the html.
- Or, you can skip the html code and work wizzywig, just like in a wiki page - right in the content-editor webpart.  This way there are no external pages, and no code nor links to mess with.  And if you want script or css in the wizzywig code, you can always edit what you have written in the html markup of the content-editor webpart.  If you want quick-and-easy text in easytabs, this is the way to go.  It is really the equivalent of linking to wiki pages, except that you can't really use them in more than one place (unless you don't mind linking to your web-part-page that houses the content-editor webpart).

I already accepted saumilm's answer because my original question was how to add wiki pages to easytabs, and he answered that question.  But this here answer is what really solved my issue.