# Adding re-usable content to Lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, content-editor-web-part

On our portal we have a subsite for signup sheets.  The signup sheets are all custom lists and contain fields for flight information and other things.

Now, we need to add directions for each signup sheet so the users will know to bring certain items with them or do certain things.

Normally we could just add a content editor to the list's page and be done with it - but there are different views.  When you add a content editor to a list web page, it only shows on the view where you added it.  Which means you have to add a Content Editor for each view and copy and paste the contents for each view.  This is quite tedious and the secretaries may not remember to do it 3 times for each list.  The directions are special for each list.

Is there a better way?  I thought to create a wiki page and display it somehow - then at least you have re-usable content.  Problem with that is that you only get a Page-Viewer WebPart which re-displays the entire page, master page and nav and all, not just the web page content.

How can I do this effectively?  I just want to display directions above the list.

Comment: I asked a similar question a long time ago: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42933/how-to-add-wiki-pages-to-web-part-page  but the scope was limited to using a wiki library.  I am willing to do this in any suitable fashion.

Comment: Man! This site is slow sometimes.

Comment: Sometimes it is even slower than slow.  I wonder if there is a better place to get help and answers.

Comment: 4 days so far, no votes, no comments, not even a close-vote.  sigh.

Comment: 16 days...  wow, is there a better place to go?